# Choosing Between SSG and Standard Configuration for next-i18next: Is it Worth Implementing SSG for Multilingual Support in Next.js?

Tags: next.js, next-i18next

I am implementing multilingual support in Next.js and considering the use of Static Site Generation (SSG) configuration based on the documentation and examples available on GitHub (https://github.com/i18next/next-i18next/tree/master/examples). However, I am questioning whether it makes sense for my site, as I won't be generating it statically using next export.

According to an article I read (https://locize.com/blog/next-i18n-static/), it seems that SSG configuration is only justified when using next export. I am uncertain whether to stick with this configuration or switch to a standard one.

In essence, my question is: Is it justified to use SSG configuration for next-i18next if my application does not generate static pages using next export?